# Not able to access classes

Tags: java, class, methods

I am trying to code a small project and am still new to the idea of classes and having my programming being more object-oriented.

I have made a class however when I try to implement its variables in a different class it won't work. The error I receive is "missing method body".

I am also having an issue with accessing methods/classes in general - I am unable to initialize my classes for some reason in Main. I consistently get a message saying to change my variables to static (even though I have been advised not to do so).

I hope this makes sense. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

This is my Class Door

```
 class Door {

    String description;
    int damage;
    String keyItem;

    boolean checkItem(String item) {
        if (Objects.equals(keyItem, "") || Objects.equals(item, keyItem)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Door(String description, int damage, String keyItem, boolean checkItem){

    }

 }
```

This is when I try to implement into another class

```
class HardRoom extends Room {
    public HardRoom() {
        
    }

    Door[] doors = new Door[4];
    doors[0] = new Door("A wooden red door, it stares at you intently. You notice a few chips engraved onto the door. What kind of damage have people tried inflicting on this door..?", -2, "strawberry", false);
```

This is my Main method where I cannot actually create my new Room, HardRoom, HarderRoom or Player without making them all static.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    while (true) {
        Room entrance = new Room();
        HardRoom doorRoom = new HardRoom();
        HarderRoom keyRoom = new HarderRoom();
        Player newPlayer = new Player();
        newPlayer.init();
```

Please let me know if I need to show any other snippets of code, thank you.

Comment: Classes contain methods, fields, and rarely initializers and other types. Your class contains statements (`doors[0] = ...`). Those cannot be put in a class. After all, when do you imagine that would run? If you want that to run when `new HardRoom()` is executed, put it in the constructor.

Comment: Format your block of code here by either indenting all lines by four spaces OR wrapping in a pair of triple back-ticks.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

> *'... I have made a class however when I try to implement its variables in a different class it won't work. The error I receive is "missing method body". ...'*

You can only declare *[members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)* in the *class scope*.

```java
class HardRoom extends Room {
    Door[] doors = new Door[4];
    
    public HardRoom() {
        doors[0] = new Door("A wooden red door, it stares at you intently. You notice a few chips engraved onto the door. What kind of damage have people tried inflicting on this door..?", -2, "strawberry", false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oriented Object Programming comes with a lot of concepts that you need to know in order to not breakdown in front of errors.
There are two concepts here that can help you deal with these errors :

- **Visibility** (of variables and methods): The default visibility of your variables is *public*, which is not often a good idea when dealing with class fields. With the right visibility, you will get more specific errors.
- **Static** (variables and methods) :
  They are variables and methods that belong to a class rather than instances of the class.
  Here is an example :
  Let's say you have a class A:

  public class A{

  ```
  static int i = 0;
  int j ;

  public A(int k){
    this.i = k;
  }
  public static printI(){
    System.out.println(this.i);
  }
  public printJ(){
    System.out.println(this.j);
  }
  ```

}

Then :

```
A a = new A();
A b = new B();

a.printI() # 0

a.i++; 
a.j++;
a.printI() # 1
A.printI() #1
a.printJ(); # 1
b.printJ(); # 0
```

As you can see, i is shared by a and b.

**And even A**, the class itself. That means that you don't need the instantiate an object of A in order to manipulate i.
It's the same thing like when you do Math.PI (PI is a static variable of Math class).
So if you get this, you can also understand that a **static method can't manipulate non-static variables** (because a non-static variable is born at instantiation of an object of the class while a static variable doesn't need that).

In your case, main is (generally) a static method, that's why it asks you to change variables to static.

There are many basic notions like those in order to code in Java. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/default.asp) is a good lite java tutorial.

Comment: Thank you! So it is just a case of seeing which classes/variables/methods to declare static/non-static and public/private/etc.?

Comment: Yeah and it is quite well explained in the link I provided. Please, can you check and upvote my answer if it solved your problem?